# Redirect to previous page in PHP but remove all URL variables

Tags: php

By URL Variables, I mean the (file)?variable=value type thing, I know you can use

```
 header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."?variable=value");
 exit();
```

but that also returns the previously used variable in the URL, causing it to look like:

```
https://(url).com/file.php?error=error?error=error?error=error?error=error
```

after a few times. Is there a way to remove all the? variables after the file extension or is there a function in PHP for redirecting the user back to the last page but dropping those variables?

Comment: Why not just eliminate them from the header call?

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: First of all, your header is not coded correctly - did you copy and paste, or just type in something?